# How to extract the sound track from a flv file

Tags: mac, flv

Is there anyway to extract the sound track from a flv file on MacOS X?
If yes, what are the tool/ways I can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use MPlayer:

```
$ mplayer -dumpaudio input.flv
```

This command dumps the whole audio track in the original format into a file called "stream.dump". Thus, the file's audio track is dumped lossless.

Alternatively, try FFmpeg:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.flv -f mp3 -vn -acodec copy output.mp3
```

Comment: Thanks. A related question. Can you please tell me if it is possible to cut off the first 3 seconds of a mp3 file on Mac using mplayer or ffmpeg?

Comment: Yes, just use the -ss parameter. See also http://activearchives.org/wiki/Cookbook#Editing_with_mplayer_.2F_mencoder

Answer (score 1):

You can use the freeware named [FLV to Audio Converter for Mac](http://www.brothersoft.com/free-flv-to-audio-converter-for-mac-225027.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use AudioExtractor for this ([web](http://www.aoamedia.com/audioextractor.htm))

Answer (score 0):

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/): all platforms, all manner of video processing tasks including saving audio (optionally without a re-encode quality loss, where possible).